# Binding a ttkCombobox when a Button is pressed - Python

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I'm using Python 3.6.0 and I want to save the value of my combobox only when I hit my "Confirm Results" button. I have done a fair bit of searching - but maybe I have the wrong terminology - and I can't find the way to do this.

I am assuming the issues is with my line *self.firstfaction_ent.bind("Button-1", self.firstfaction_onEnter)*. I am fairly confident that "Button-1" is not correct - however I have been trying everything.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Application(Frame):

   def __init__(self, master):

# Initialise the Frame
      super(Application, self).__init__(master)
      self.grid()
      self.create_widgets()

   def create_widgets(self):

   #Define Combobox for Faction
       self.firstfaction_ent=ttk.Combobox(self,textvariable=varSymbol, state='readonly')
       self.firstfaction_ent.bind("<Button-1>", self.firstfaction_onEnter)      
       self.firstfaction_ent['values']=Faction
       self.firstfaction_ent.grid(row=2, column=1)

  #create a submit button
       self.enter_bttn = Button(self,text = "Confirm Your Results", command = self.firstfaction_onEnter).grid(row=7, column=1)

   def firstfaction_onEnter(self, event):
       Faction_First = varSymbol.get()
       print(Faction_First)

#main

root = Tk()

#Window Title & size
root.title("Sports Carnival Entry Window")
root.geometry("600x500")

varSymbol=StringVar(root, value='')
varSecondFaction=StringVar(root, value='')
Faction = ["Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Red"]

#create a frame in the window
app = Application(root)

root.mainloop( )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `confirm_button` to capture the selection in the `combo box`; there is no need to bind the combo box selection to the capture; you also do not need to pass an event to `firstfaction_onEnter`; you can directly use the combo_box to obtain the value of the selection.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Application(Frame):

   def __init__(self, master):

# Initialise the Frame
      super(Application, self).__init__(master)
      self.grid()
      self.create_widgets()

   def create_widgets(self):

   #Define Combobox for Faction
       self.firstfaction_ent = ttk.Combobox(self, textvariable=varSymbol, state='readonly')
#        self.firstfaction_ent.bind("<Button-1>", self.firstfaction_onEnter)      
       self.firstfaction_ent['values'] = Faction
       self.firstfaction_ent.grid(row=2, column=1)

  #create a submit button
       self.enter_bttn = Button(self, text="Confirm Your Results", command=self.firstfaction_onEnter).grid(row=7, column=1)

   def firstfaction_onEnter(self):
       Faction_First = self.firstfaction_ent.get()
       print(Faction_First)

#main

root = Tk()

#Window Title & size
root.title("Sports Carnival Entry Window")
root.geometry("600x500")

varSymbol=StringVar(root, value='')
varSecondFaction=StringVar(root, value='')
Faction = ["Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Red"]

#create a frame in the window
app = Application(root)

root.mainloop( )
```